# Select element not working in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I write the web page; I have the problem with `active element`.

You can see to know my issues.

[image]

I don't know it seems to fail when I tried to click on the second tab or third tab (it only working with the first tab), and I can't click another child element tab.

Can you see my [pen](https://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/amdmYL).

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

 (function ($) { 
  $('.tab ul.tabs').addClass('active').find('> li:eq(0)').addClass('current');
  
  $('.tab ul.tabs li a').click(function (g) { 
   var tab = $(this).closest('.tab'), 
    index = $(this).closest('li').index();
      console.log(tab + ' ' + index); 
   
   tab.find('ul.tabs > li').removeClass('current');
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
   
   tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item').not('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideUp();
   tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideDown();
   
   g.preventDefault();
  } );
 })(jQuery);

});

var tabsFn = (function() {
  
  function init() {
    setHeight();
  }
  
  function setHeight() {
    var $tabPane = $('.tab-pane'),
        tabsHeight = $('.nav-tabs').height();
    
    $tabPane.css({
      height: tabsHeight
    });
  }
    
  $(init);
})();
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);
.tab {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #888;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.tabs {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.tabs a {
  background-color: #eff0f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #87d3b7;
}

.tabs_item {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.tabs_item h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #87d3b7;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.tabs_item img {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.tabs_item:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.current a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #87d3b7;
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.badge {
  background-color: #777;
}

.tabs-left {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-tabs li a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}
.nav-tabs li a:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}
.nav-tabs .glyphicon {
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs .active .glyphicon {
  color: #333;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  border: 0;
}

.tab-content {
  margin-left: 45px;
}
.tab-content .tab-pane {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.tab-content .active {
  display: block;
}

.list-group {
  width: 100%;
}
.list-group .list-group-item {
  height: 50px;
}
.list-group .list-group-item h4, .list-group .list-group-item span {
  line-height: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#">Tab01</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab02</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab03</a></li>
 </ul> <!-- / tabs -->

 <div class="tab_content">

  <div class="tabs_item">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="tabs-left">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#e" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#f" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
               <div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">
                   <h3>Who do you Love?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Jen &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="b">
                   <h3>What's your Favorite?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Crystals &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="d">Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="e">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="f">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
               </div><!-- /tab-content -->
             </div><!-- /tabbable -->
           </div><!-- /col -->
         </div><!-- /row -->
       </div><!-- /container -->
  </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->

  <div class="tabs_item">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="tabs-left">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#e" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#f" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
               <div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">
                   <h3>Who do you Love?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Jen &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="b">
                   <h3>What's your Favorite?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Crystals &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="d">Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="e">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="f">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
               </div><!-- /tab-content -->
             </div><!-- /tabbable -->
           </div><!-- /col -->
         </div><!-- /row -->
       </div><!-- /container -->
  </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->

  <div class="tabs_item">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="tabs-left">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#e" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#f" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
               <div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">
                   <h3>Who do you Love?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Jen &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="b">
                   <h3>What's your Favorite?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Crystals &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="d">Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="e">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="f">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
               </div><!-- /tab-content -->
             </div><!-- /tabbable -->
           </div><!-- /col -->
         </div><!-- /row -->
       </div><!-- /container -->
  </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->
  
 </div> <!-- / tab_content -->
</div> <!-- / tab -->
```

Comment: On a single web page you cannot use same id again and again. The ID should be unique in the entire page. If you will use same ID this will conflict and you will not get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this [codepen](http://codepen.io/aavrug/pen/ORrbkR)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

 (function ($) { 
  $('.tab ul.tabs').addClass('active').find('> li:eq(0)').addClass('current');
  
  $('.tab ul.tabs li a').click(function (g) { 
   var tab = $(this).closest('.tab'), 
    index = $(this).closest('li').index();
      console.log(tab + ' ' + index); 
   
   tab.find('ul.tabs > li').removeClass('current');
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
   
   tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item').not('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideUp();
   tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideDown();
   
   g.preventDefault();
  } );
 })(jQuery);

});

var tabsFn = (function() {
  
  function init() {
    setHeight();
  }
  
  function setHeight() {
    var $tabPane = $('.tab-pane'),
        tabsHeight = $('.nav-tabs').height();
    
    $tabPane.css({
      height: tabsHeight
    });
  }
    
  $(init);
})();
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);
.tab {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #888;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.tabs {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.tabs a {
  background-color: #eff0f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #87d3b7;
}

.tabs_item {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.tabs_item h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #87d3b7;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.tabs_item img {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.tabs_item:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.current a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #87d3b7;
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.badge {
  background-color: #777;
}

.tabs-left {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-tabs li a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}
.nav-tabs li a:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}
.nav-tabs .glyphicon {
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs .active .glyphicon {
  color: #333;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  border: 0;
}

.tab-content {
  margin-left: 45px;
}
.tab-content .tab-pane {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.tab-content .active {
  display: block;
}

.list-group {
  width: 100%;
}
.list-group .list-group-item {
  height: 50px;
}
.list-group .list-group-item h4, .list-group .list-group-item span {
  line-height: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#">Tab01</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab02</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab03</a></li>
 </ul> <!-- / tabs -->

 <div class="tab_content">

  <div class="tabs_item">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="tabs-left">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#e" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#f" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
               <div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">
                   <h3>Who do you Love?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Jen &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="b">
                   <h3>What's your Favorite?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Crystals &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="d">Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="e">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="f">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
               </div><!-- /tab-content -->
             </div><!-- /tabbable -->
           </div><!-- /col -->
         </div><!-- /row -->
       </div><!-- /container -->
  </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->

  <div class="tabs_item">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="tabs-left">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#a1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#b1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#c1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#d1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#e1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#f1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
               <div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="a1">
                   <h3>Who do you Love?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Jen &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="b1">
                   <h3>What's your Favorite?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Crystals &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="c1">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="d1">Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="e1">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="f1">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
               </div><!-- /tab-content -->
             </div><!-- /tabbable -->
           </div><!-- /col -->
         </div><!-- /row -->
       </div><!-- /container -->
  </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->

  <div class="tabs_item">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="tabs-left">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#a2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#b2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#c2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#d2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#e2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#f2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
               <div class="tab-content">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="a2">
                   <h3>Who do you Love?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Jen &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="b2">
                   <h3>What's your Favorite?</h3>
                   <ul class="list-group pull-left">
                     <li class="list-group-item">
                       <h4>Crystals &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="badge pull-right">100%</span></h4>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="c2">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="d2">Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="e2">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="f2">Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
               </div><!-- /tab-content -->
             </div><!-- /tabbable -->
           </div><!-- /col -->
         </div><!-- /row -->
       </div><!-- /container -->
  </div> <!-- / tabs_item -->
  
 </div> <!-- / tab_content -->
</div> <!-- / tab -->
```

Comment: I found you only change `id`. I also change `id` but it not working like your pen. Are you change js/css?

Comment: No I have only changed ```id```. I just made them unique.

Comment: You save my life. Thank you very much.

Comment: My fault, because I forget link `<a href="#b"`. :)